# 2D augmented reality with sensor issue

Tags: augmented-reality, sensors

I'm making a "geolocational AR app" in which I use Paint() to draw bitmap on my screen with the use of sensors to do some translation so that my image will only be shown at a specific point.
I've done everything

However, the image shakes while I present it.

I really want the effect as the following videos presents

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8U3vWETmk2U

I've implemented low pass filter to ease the situation but it is still not as steady as the images from the video.

This is how I achieve AR movement

```
float dx = (float) ( (canvas.getWidth()/ horizontalFOV) * (Math.toDegrees(orientation[0])-curBearingTo));
float dy = (float) ( (canvas.getHeight()/ verticalFOV) * Math.toDegrees(orientation[1]));

canvas.translate(0.0f, 0.0f-dy);

canvas.translate(0.0f-dx, 0.0f);
```

The curBearingTois the result of android location API: BearingTo(location, destination)

And this is how I get Orientation matrix

```
if (lastAccelerometer != null && lastCompass != null) {
        boolean gotRotation = SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(rotation,
                identity, lastAccelerometer, lastCompass);
        if (gotRotation) {
            // remap such that the camera is pointing straight down the Y
            // axis
            SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(rotation,
                    SensorManager.AXIS_X, SensorManager.AXIS_Z,
                    cameraRotation);
            // orientation vector
            SensorManager.getOrientation(cameraRotation, orientation);
 }
```

Any suggestion?